# Non-Generic CompositePresentationEvent and EventSubscription?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, prism, eventaggregator, prism-4

I am trying to create a `TPayLoad`-free `CompositePresentationEvent`, that its delegate is parameterless.

I want to have a global application event that takes no parameters such as `UserLoggedInEvent`, `UserGotIdleEvent` etc. etc.

How should this be done with the Prism 4.0 event aggregation system?

Comment: you could use <object> as parameter and pass null to it.

Comment: I know but that's really clunky. I posted a [work item](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/workitem/8103) at Prism on the codeplex site, please vote for it, it's definitely sure it's very compelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/2009/07/simplify-prism-event-aggregator.html) post clarified some things for me.
Anyway I realize now the the Prism EA system is really clumzy tho.

[Here](http://codepaste.net/uf9isv) are some extension methods that focus on reducing the verbosity of the EA.

Answer (score 0):

For logging and handling roles and permissions around the application and sub modules it's best to use Interfaces instead of event aggregation system.